# Distribution of Android app at a trade fair

Tags: android, deployment

I apologize if this question is a bit broad, but as I am new to deployment I was looking for some advice.

I have an app which I would like to have passers by at a trade fair booth be able to install and run quickly with minimal effort. To make sure there is no unidentified developer warning, it will have to be on the Play Store. Is there a more streamlined manner for a user to install the app than just search the store manually?

A QR code would work but not everyone would have a QR code scanner app so that would potentially be more user effort.

EDIT: by unidentified developer warning I mean the unknown source setting needing to be enabled

Comment: What you can do is upload the apk of the app to some file hosting website. Get its downloading url, shorten that url and paste the url posters at  your booth. In addition you can offer hotspot to let them download that app on your expenses.

Comment: The probelm with that is the unidentified developer warning which we would like to avoid

Comment: Is there anything like `unidentified developer warning` there for android. I don't think so.

Comment: well, that warning when trying to install an app not from play store. the setting you need to change to be able to run such apps

Comment: You can ask for their devices, connect that device to your laptop and using **adb install** command install your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nice option would be to have beacon using something like https://developers.google.com/nearby/notifications/overview.

"As a developer, you can associate your app or website with a BLE beacon or BLE- capable smart device. Android users near that device or beacon will receive a notification that leads to either an app install, a mobile website, or directly to your app if it's already installed. "

Comment: that sounds very promising, hadn't thought of that

Comment: We can't ensure that every one would have BLE enabled devices. Because, it came on later devices.

Comment: whilst that is true, it has been around for 5 or so years

Answer (score 1):

If you have an email list you can send your apk via email. A user would have to one-click in an attachment to install the app. 
Keep in mind, the user has to allow `"Unknown sources"` in Settings.

Comment: if the app is on the playstore would the apk be recognized from an external source?

Comment: what do you mean exactly?

Comment: so that the unknown sources setting wouldn't need changing

Comment: you have to have it ticked if you want to install any app in any other way than GooglePlay even if it is published in it I think

Comment: my comment was more whether by the app being in the playstore would mean downloading it from elsewhere would let the phone match the identity of the apk